# Fecha de hoy en Date con un formato determinado

Tags: java

Teng que setear la fecha del momento de compilar con un formato determinado a un objeto.
He sacado esto

```
 Date fecha = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            String date = inputFormat.format(fecha);
            Date fecha2 = new Date(date);
```

Pero esta deprecado y ademas no funciona. Este es el formato qeu debe aparecer 2022-02-01T10:45:00.000Z"

Comment: Usa `inputFormat.parse( <tu string >)` en lugar de  `new Date(date);`. La conversión de `String` a `Date` se hace con el método `parse` del objeto `SimpleDateFormat`. (Es lo único `deprecated` que veo en tu código)

Comment: Perdona, ¿puedes confirmar que lo que necesitas es la fecha **en el momento de compilarse el fichero java**???

Comment: Por cierto, he visto que la "Z" la pones como una constante.... En realidad es la zona horaria, creo que se refiere a la hora Zulu (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado#Hora_Zul%C3%BA). En realidad debería parsearse también, pero me parece que no coincide con la descripción de zonas horarias de java

Comment: Hola @unknow el valor que necesitas con el formato que aplicas es el de la variable date, imprime su valor y veras que no necesitas realizar más cambios.

Answer (score 0):

He ejecutado tu código y parece ser que el punto donde hay un problema es éste:

```
Date fecha2 = new Date(date);
```

que me aparece marcado como *deprecated* el constructor `Date( String )`. Pero éso tiene fácil solución:

```
Date fecha2 = inputFormat.parse( date );
```

Que además te permite especificar el formato de la fecha que se va a leer.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando aplicas el formato de fecha "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" ya obtienes el valor de esta fecha con el formato,

```
 Date fecha = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
 String date = inputFormat.format(fecha);
 System.out.println(date);
```

por lo tanto aquí el valor de `date` ya tiene este formato:

```
2022-04-20T11:22:03.537Z
```

y este es el valor que necesitas, no necesitas crear otra instancia de Date.

---

Si deseas volver a convertir el valor de `data` a tipo `Date` lo debes realizar de esta forma:

```
    try {
         Date fecha2 = inputFormat.parse( date );
         
      } catch (ParseException ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
```